# ZSH tab-completion for git commands not working as expected

Tags: git, zsh, tab-completion

I recently got a new MacBook for work and had to setup a new dev environment, and the tab-completion for git commands isn't working the way it does on my old machine. I used to be able to type `git checkout 1234` and it would tab-complete to `git checkout EXAMPLE-1234`, but now it doesn't. It also seems to be case sensitive and doesn't recognise any branches when I type `git checkout example-`, I have to type `git checkout EXAMPLE-` for it to suggest anything. Also, if I just type `git che`, it doesn't show me the different command options like it does in the docs, it just completes to `git checkout`. I feel like I've tried all the solutions I've found in different threads, and nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

For reference, here's my `.zshrc`:

```
export ZSH="/Users/adambelton/.oh-my-zsh"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"
plugins=(
  git
  zsh-autosuggestions
  zsh-syntax-highlighting
)
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

Comment: Can you show us the `.zshrc` of your old machine, especially the `plugins=` line?

Comment: It's the same. Same plugins. The only difference is that I was using nvm on the old machine, so I was exporting `NVM_DIR`.

Comment: To be clear, if I type `git checkout EXAMPLE-1`, I _do_ see all the options for branches that begin that way, so _some_ form of tab-completion is loading, it's just doesn't seem to be the behaviour explained in `https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Appendix-A%3A-Git-in-Other-Environments-Git-in-Zsh`, and it's not working the way it used to.